# debian installation without internet connection

Tags: debian, qemu, embedded-linux, arm

I want to install some Debian distributions (Grip, Crush, Lenny...)
for arm / armel architectures.

www.emdebian.org/

I'm referring to this guide:

> http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_arm_qemu.PHP

The problem I have is that I don't have internet connection with My Linux VM or Qemu I am behind a Proxy. I want to know is there a way where I can dl all the needed files and save them to disk that I don´t need an I.c. during the installation?
I am working under Windows now.

Comment: 8 questions isn´t much?

Comment: Well i am working on arm boards + c# development and i am totally new on embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a local repository mirror?

Also there appears to be a syntax for describing local apt sources ala 
    file:/my/local/apt/repo stable main contrib non-free
but I can't find apt-get docs, also this is not just dumping a buch of debs, its setting up a repo that happens to be on the local filesystem(or on cd/dvd).